# Dropdown within a DetailsView: show text based on stored value

Tags: asp.net

I have a database table called Employees that has an ID number, First Name, Last Name, and SupervisorID for each employee.  The SupervisorID stored for an employee equals the ID number of that employee's supervisor.

I want to have a DetailsView control that can edit these fields for an employee.  The Supervisor field needs to be a dropdown that stores the SupervisorID as the value, and shows the supervisor's First Name and Last Name as it's text.

I've looked around a lot and was able to figure out how to create the dropdown to select and show SupervisorID's.  Where I'm stuck is how do I change the code below to store the SupervisorID, but show the Supervisor's name as it's text?

Here's the code for the Supervisor dropdown within my DetailsList:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Supervisor" SortExpression="SupervisorID">
             <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="SupervisorID" DataValueField="SupervisorID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SupervisorID") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [SupervisorID] FROM [Employees]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SupervisorID") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Any ideas for what I can change to accomplish my goal?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: You want to update supervisor id of each employee when button (Update) click event?

Comment: @Thit Lwin Oo Yes I want to update the employee's supervisorID, but I'd like the dropdown to show the supervisor's name instead of their ID.  So the dropdown needs the SupervisorID as it's value, but able to show the name as it's text.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are some code for you to check. You need to modify where employee list is retrieved. I code static data. Anything you don't clear, let me know.

-----------------------aspx code------

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvEmp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        onrowdatabound="grvEmp_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee Id" DataField="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dlList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text=" -- select supervisor --"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" 
        onclick="btnUpdate_Click" />
```

-----------------code behind --------------------------
//put this method where data bind to gridview

```
 BindGrid();

private void BindGrid()
        {
            //emp list
            //change here.. load employee list from your database
            dtEmp = new DataTable();
            dtEmp.Columns.Add("ID");
            dtEmp.Columns.Add("Name");
            dtEmp.Columns.Add("SupervisorId");

            DataRow dr = dtEmp.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "1";
            dr[1] = "John";

            dr = dtEmp.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "2";
            dr[1] = "Mary";
            dtEmp.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dtEmp.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "3";
            dr[1] = "Edward";
            dtEmp.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dtEmp.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "4";
            dr[1] = "Phippip";
            dtEmp.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dtEmp.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "5";
            dr[1] = "James";
            dtEmp.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dtEmp.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "6";
            dr[1] = "Jason";
            dtEmp.Rows.Add(dr);

            grvEmp.DataSource = dtEmp;
            grvEmp.DataBind();
        }
```

---------in gridview row data bond event.. for supervisor dropdown list

```
protected void grvEmp_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList dl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("dlList");

                if (dl != null)
                {
                    dl.DataSource = dtEmp;
                    dl.DataTextField = "Name";
                    dl.DataValueField = "ID";
                    dl.DataBind();

                    //remove own id
                    dl.Items.Remove(dl.Items.FindByValue(e.Row.Cells[0].Text));
                }

            }
        }
```

-----------------on update button click event to save supervisor of each employee

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // get emp id and thier supervisor id

            for (int i = 0; i < grvEmp.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                GridViewRow row = grvEmp.Rows[i];

                //get emp id 
                string empId = row.Cells[0].Text;

                //get supervisor id
                DropDownList dl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("dlList");
                string supervisorId = (dl != null) ? dl.SelectedValue : "";

                if (supervisorId != "")
                {
                    //update supervisor id of employee here to DB
                    //you can keep emp n supervisor id pair.. and save all only one time after looping of gridivew
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'm trying to do this within a DetailsList.  I see that this code is for a GridView.  Would I have to do this differently for a DetailsView?  Thanks for the help, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Not much different. You can change DataList and put code in relevant event.